# Dropdowns in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, angular-ui-bootstrap, javascript-databinding

I have angularjs interdependable dropdowns, here is a demo `plunker`: http://plnkr.co/edit/mIFCKKO5Azr4ljyoge5r?p=preview. Now when I select an option from first(country) dropdown, I want the second (state)dropdown to be displayed as a checkbox dropdown and not the normal dropdown(like in the above plunker) and after selecting option from second multiple dropdown I should get another multiple dropdown again. Here is a sample checkbox dropdown, `fiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/michaeldeongreen/22et6sao/9/ need this to be displayd for both state and city dropdowns in my plunker.

Finally when I select a country from first normal dropdown, the second multiple dropdown menu with checkbox for selecting a state should be enabled and after selecting a state, another checkbox dropdown menu for selecting city have to be enabled. Until I select an option from first dropdown, the second and third dropdowns have to be disabled and till I select option from second dropdown third dropdown has to be disabled.

Hope anyone will help me. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you are using simple select in your plnkr and expecting it to be ng-dropdown-multiselect type. Use ng-dropdown-multiselect instead of drop-down and disable until country is not selected.

Comment: @Rakesh Chand: Thankyou for the reply.. But I didn't get the required result. Could you please alter the code in plunker.

Comment: Use this directive `ngDropdownMultiselect`(given in fiddle) in your code instead of simple drop down.

Comment: @Rakesh Chand: Got this point.. its working independently but in this case in need the dependable dropdowns, which has to fetch options based on selection of country.

Comment: Are you getting any errors while implementing ? What have you achieved so far by using the directive?

Comment: @Rakesh Chand: Here is how I have changed the code: http://plnkr.co/edit/6TfLVCSmEx3szcWUWfr0?p=preview

Comment: @Pranitha can you use third party angular modules?

Comment: @Minato: Which one can I use here.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/SMUXY0AM4RSsbHrR3Nu7?p=preview

Comment: @Abhilash P A- Pullelil: Thanks fr the reply, but what I need is first dropdown has to be normal dropdown and second has to be multiselect checkbox. For example if I select India from first dropdown, the states: AndraPradesh, Assam, Orissa has to be displayed in multiselect dropdown.